# while loop not stopping on condition match

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a WHILE loop running that won't stop.  If I change the while condition to $x<50 it would do what I expect, but return a lot of empty results.  I'd like to stop once there is no more data.

If I check the condition by setting $x=20 and do a var_dump of $y it will return NULL, so I can't figure out why the loop won't stop when $y==NULL.

I keep getting a Fatal Error: Allowed memory exhausted.

I've tried casting the variable $y to a string and checking for $y!=="" and other variations but the loop just doesn't seem to recognize the condition and stop.

Thanks for any help.

```
$c=1;
$x=0;
$y=$xmlobj->simpleXML->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail[$x];

while($y!==NULL){
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $c] = array();
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $c]['country'] = (string)$xmlobj->simpleXML->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail->{$x}['COUNTRY'];
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $c]['fund_percentage'] = (string)$xmlobj->simpleXML->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail->{$x}['FUNDPCT'];
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $c]['index'] = (string)$xmlobj->simpleXML->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail->{$x}['Index'];

    ++$x;
    ++$c;

   }
```

Comment: `$y` never changes in the loop, so your `while()` loop is an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm assuming you're actually using `while($y!==NULL)`? Though, this should be done with a `foreach`... Something like `foreach($y as $item){ //use each array item here }`

Comment: You never change `$y` in your loop.  Try a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may need messing around with, depending on the rest of your code and whether $y is an array of arrays as I'm assuming, but it should get you back on track.

```
$count = 1;
$y=$xmlobj->simpleXML->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail[$x];

foreach($y as $row){
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $count] = array();
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $count]['country'] = $row['COUNTRY'];
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $count]['fund_percentage'] = $row['FUNDPCT'];
    $obj->table_data['country_' . $count]['index'] = $row['Index'];
    $count++;
}
```

It may seem like a small thing when coding, but readability should be key to everything you do. Even if it takes a little more time to implement, the maintainability is significantly higher.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I thought $y changed with each iteration of $x. I see now, and a foreach loop is so much better.